# Memory leak from one response of HttpClient in foreach cycle

Tags: c#, memory-leaks, garbage-collection

I have HttpClient single instance in my application. It is makes small requests many times a day. But once a day it has to make few big requests. Problem is that one of request remains in memory and not garbage collected however this response is used nowhere else. What am I doing wrong

```
public static Dictionary<MyHash, int?> DBCache { get; private set; } = new();

public static async Task UpdateCache()
{
    var result = new Dictionary<MyHash, int?>();
    foreach (MyEnum e in Enum.GetValues(typeof(MyEnum)))
    {
        var req = DbRequestString(e);
        var response = await Client.GetAsync(req);
        var responseStr = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        //this string remains in memory (1 of them)

        var db = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DbSchema>(responseStr);
        //this object remains in memory too and only 1 of them also
        foreach (var schema in db.Items)
        {
            var name = schema.Name;
            var hash = new MyHash(name, e); //struct that stores only these variables
            var value = CalculateValues(schema);
            result.Add(hash, value);
        }
        response.Dispose();
    }

    DBCache = result;
    LastUpdated = DateTime.Now;
    SaveCache();
    System.GC.Collect(); //What I tried, but this doesn't work too
}
```

```
private static void SaveCache()
{
    var cached = DBCash.ToDictionary(kvp => MyHashJson.FromHash(kvp.Key), kvp => kvp.Value);
    var collection = cached.ToArray().AsEnumerable();
    var json = new CacheJson()
    {
        LastUpdated = LastUpdated,
        Cached = collection,
    };
    var serialized = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(json, Formatting.Indented);
    using var file = File.CreateText("DBCache.json");
    file.Write(serialized);
}

public static void LoadCache()
{
    var cached = File.ReadAllText("DBCache.json");
    var json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CacheJson>(cached);
    LastUpdated = json.LastUpdated;
    var cache = json.Cached.ToDictionary(kvp => new MyHash(kvp.Key.Name, kvp.Key.E), kvp => kvp.Value);
    CachedSkins = cache;
}
```

Neither `responseStr`, nor `db` referenced anywhere. But one instance always remains in memory

[image: cropped picture from profiler]

Comment: Just a quick question: Have you tried to explicitly set them to `null` after the `response.Dispose();` call ? Like `responseStr = null; db = null;`

Comment: @PeterCsala This partially helped, the memory decreased from 1.4 gigabytes to 980. In general, it’s not bad, thanks, but when the application starts and the cache is loaded from the .json file, the consumption is about 700 mb, there is something is still clogged. I see many objects from `db` in memory. But why did it help at all, how does it work? Perhaps understanding this I can solve the problem.

Comment: @PeterCsala I noticed that the memory is littered with objects for the same `MyEnum` and it is always the last one. Others are garbaged successfully

Comment: In that case you should not call `Enum.GetValues(typeof(MyEnum)` every time when the `UpdateCache` is called. Rather store the result in a `static readonly` field.

Comment: @PeterCsala I did not quite correctly put it, the objects clogging the memory are still the same (`responseStr` and `db` properties). But only those received in the last cycle iteration are kept.

Comment: Ok, if I start dotMemory profiler there are no leaks. Memory is always stable. Maybe Visual Studio doesn't show memory consumption correctly.

Comment: Well in this case it might make sense to use a 3rd profiler as well to have a quorum :D For example [CodeTrack](https://www.getcodetrack.com/)